# Android - Custom ListView with internet images. Can't download images

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to display a custom `ListView` that has a thumbnail image and text in each row.

I have the text stored in one `ArrayList<String>` and the `URLs` to each thumbnail stored in another one.

I can get the text to appear in the list, but I can only statically/manually set the image.

**My question:** How can I make my `ImageView` download the thumbnail image and display it? Each thumbnail is unique.

Here is my code for populating the ListAdapter:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> 
{
    CustomAdapter() 
    {
        super(MyClass.this, R.layout.listrows, R.id.txtAddress,propertyAddress);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ViewHolder holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();

        if (holder==null) 
        {                         
            holder=new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }

        //I tried this,
        holder.icon.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageList.get(position).toString()));
        //But I get a NullPointer

        return(row);
    }
}
```

Also, my `ViewHolder` class is pretty normal:

```
class ViewHolder
{
    ImageView icon=null;
    ViewHolder(View base)   {
        this.icon=(ImageView)base.findViewById(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setImageUri is to set a local position. not for the internet.

try to use [ImageDownloader](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/ImageDownloader.html).